# fapws3 server restart gives warning and service is unavailable

Tags: server, process, django

I run a fapws3 server for my django project on a virtual develoment server and all worked fine. After a standard settings changing of a template directory my server wouldn't start again. Instead a `http`-request returns "The service is not available. Please try again later.". Additionally: If I run

`sudo /etc/init.d/fapws3 restart`

the return is

```
Restarting FAPWS3: fapws3start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 7786: No such process
start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 7802: No such process
start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 7806: No such process
start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 7814: No such process
start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 7820: No such process
```

Which seems to be perfectly correct, because if I check the running processes with

`ps aux | grep -i manage`

I only get one process

```
ct         7923  0.0  0.1   3876   824 pts/0    S+   19:12   0:00 grep -i manage
```

But if I try to kill this by hand, It says

```
kill -9 7923
-bash: kill: (7923) - No such process
```

as well. This is again correct, because if I run

`ps aux | grep -i manage`

it returns me always a higher process id afterwards (i.e.):

```
ct        7935  0.0  0.1   3876   820 pts/0    S+   19:15   0:00 grep -i manage
```

Just running 'sudo /etc/init.d/fapws3 stop' and 'sudo /etc/init.d/fapws3 start' does not change anything.

Any suggestions what I could try to make my server running again? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent hours on this problem until I found out, with the following command:

```
sudo netstat -anp -p | grep 80
```

that there are many processes waiting on close on the port. After killing them by hand it was possible to initialize a new instance of pound.